# Is it possible to do quick tests in ASP.NET MVC to hit break points in Actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC5.

I am debugging some code in an application that I am not fully aware of. I need to test code at an "Action" level where I have set some breakpoints. I was hoping for a method where I could directly invoke the Controller Action code to check its variable assigns. When you "run" the application, in Visual Studio, the entire application is run in the browser and I then have to navigate to where I think the logic is called to trigger the breakpoint which can be a bit tricky, as I am not fully familiar with the web app yet.

Could this be a feature of the debugger, as I only want to run the current Controller Action, and directly...

Thanks in advance

Comment: In many cases we add a separate console application project to the solution, only use of which will be to invoke components. Inside the main function, you can simply create an object of controller class and call action. Same idea is also used in unit test projects too...but in such cases you need to write the unit test cases.

Comment: Thanks for this, certainly an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are few solutions.**

1. Web Debugging applications
2. Unit Testing

**Web Debugging application**

One popular web debugger is [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), where you can prepare and catch http requests and replay them or compose them from nothing, and they will be ready to submit, and analyse however you desire.

**Unit Testing example**

1. Right-Click **Solution** -> New Project -> Test -> **Unit Test Project**
2. Project name naming convention *CurrentProjectName.Tests*
3. Add the bellow Test code
4. Click on the MenuBar **Test** -> **Debug** -> **All Tests**

**Code:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReturnsDetailsView() // Test name
{
    // Controller to test
    var controller = new HomeController();
    // Action to test with parameters
    var result = controller.SomeAction("Param1") as ViewResult;
    // Check the following for True
    Assert.AreEqual("SomeAction", result.ViewName);
}
```

**Few Links:**

[MVC Unit Testing Unleashed](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/763928/MVC-Unit-Testing-Unleashed)
[Creating Unit Tests for ASP.NET MVC Controllers](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/01/15/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-controllers.aspx)

Comment: Preference is to use Unit Testing, but we are not sure of the best and simplest approach to this, especially with Controller Action code. Would you be so kind to elaborate on the Unit Testing approach please.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have also tried using fiddler, however I am not sure it will work to trigger a debug breakpoint, since it invokes its own, non debug call, I believe. Anyway the breakpoint is not being called. Perhaps I am not doing something correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this Unit Test code. Having looked at the problem again, this could be tricky as I want to check for private property values. For this use case, I think web debugging is going to be more suitable, but I am unsure how to invoke the current Action Method directly to invoke the Breakpoint.

Comment: This is a good answer, so will mark it as such. However my requirement has moved on so will open a new question. Thank you for your help.